# PHP server exited signal: killed

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine-orm, apache2, symfony4

4.8
The server was running perfectly before i initialized my logging protocol.
Sorry for sending so much information below, just want to make sure yall understand the context.

I get this log after i send the request :

```
[Application    ] Jul 27 14:49:01 |INFO | SECURI User has been authenticated successfully. username="max.loua@nouvellesdonnes.com"
Shut down, bye!
```

That message is followed by a

```
PHP server exited unexpectedly: signal:killed
```

I'm using for the auth:

```
Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication;
```

with all the required components (my IDE inserts them automatically `PHPStorm`)

the `security.yaml` file is setup this way with a `default_target_path` option.

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User: bcrypt
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
      database_users:
          entity: { class: App\Entity\User, property: email}
```

default path on logging params:

```
form_login:
                check_path: security_login
                login_path: security_login
                default_target_path: theme_add
```

A basic login function in my security controller :

```
public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils){
            return new Response($this->twig->render(
                'security/login.html.twig',
                [
                    'last_username' => $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername(),
                    'error' => $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError()
                ]
            ));
    }
```

The user is obviously authenticated, the browser awaits and then suddenly the servers shut down i have looked everywhere to find what was the issue online but nothing.

I have looked at my log output on apache2 and i get this error `cat /var/log/apache2/error.log` :
`[mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 42135] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long 2 days looking online and trying to fix the issue, it came from a function in my entity (User), the function in question was `serialize()`.

```
public function serialize()
    {
        return $this->serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->last_name,
            $this->email,
            $this->job,
            $this->password,
            $this->username
        ));
    }
```

the function was looping cause of `$this->` all i had to do is to remove it.